# Oregon decriminalized possession of certain drugs. Is the act of buying still illegal?

Tags: oregon, drugs

Oregon decriminalized "the possession" of certain drugs. But the act of manufacturing and selling drugs is still illegal, according to this article:

https://www.opb.org/article/2020/11/04/oregon-measure-110-decriminalize-drugs/

My question is: is the act of "purchasing" these legal drugs still an offense? The measure says:

> A "yes" vote supported making personal non-commercial possession of a controlled substance no more than a Class E violation (max fine of $100 fine) and establishing a drug addiction treatment and recovery program funded in part by the state's marijuana tax revenue and state prison savings.

It says "possession" is now a minor violation. But what if you get caught in the act of "purchasing" it? Is that still a crime? I couldn't find any mention of it.

Comment: At a minimum, Oregon can't make federal controlled substances acts inapplicable.

Answer (score 7):

[It's still illegal to sell most drugs like that in Oregon](https://sbtreatment.com/blog/oregon-decriminalized/)

> Oregon did not pass the law to make the state a haven for drug users. It’s still illegal to purchase, carry, and consume illicit substances in the state of Oregon. Measure 110 will change the laws around the possession of decriminalized substances. Under the new law, carrying small amounts of any of these drugs is a civil violation that is punishable by a fine. Before, having any quantity of illicit drugs was a misdemeanor and was automatically punishable by jail time.

It is, however, legal to grow and sell marijuana, [provided the seller is licensed to do so](https://www.oregon.gov/olcc/marijuana/pages/default.aspx).

Comment: When you say "it's illegal to sell" - is it legal to buy? Would it be legal for me to inherit my grandads stash when he unfortunately passes away? Or if I find some in the street (apart from the fact that finding + keeping anything that isn't mine might be illegal).

Comment: I'm assuming this is more of a "I found grandad's stash" thing. If so, it would likely fall under the "personal possession" exception (he didn't sell it to you, after all). Same for any you just happen to find on the street. As far as buying, the above notes it's still illegal to buy controlled substances (heroin, cocaine, etc), except for licensed marijuana.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, many of these substances are still illegal to posses under Federal Law, which means the DEA can still prosecute you for drug offenses even when Oregan does not.  All that said, unless you are a major player in trafficking illegal drugs, you're likely not going to have to worry about Hank Schrader and pals knocking on your door.   As with most crime in the U.S., the state is more likely to prosecute than the Federal Government.

Comment: He's going to break bad